# How can I split one column into two in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-science

I have a dataframe in R that contains a column with location coordinates. The issue is that the column entries are formatted in long,lat format (ie- 71.22,29.88) and Im trying to separate this one column into two separate columns- one with just longitude information and one with just latitude information.  Additionally some column entries are 0,0 so I would like to get rid of those.  Is there a way to do all of this in R?  I tried using a for loop and iterating over the columns and using regex to check for the proper format but this wasn't working well,

Thanks!

Comment: It would be nice to include a minimal reproducible example (or an example of the dataset) for others with the same question:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wee  can  use `separate` to split the 'location' column into 'lat', 'lon' after removing rows with '0,0' in the 'location' column

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     filter(location != '0,0') %>%
     separate(location, into = c('lat', 'lon'), sep=",")
```